# What is the time between points called on a graph?

Tags: terminology

If I have a line graph that has a point for every day along the x axis and another graph that has a point for every month what is the name for the distance between points on the x axis?  The _____ is 1 day vs the _____ is 1 month?

Is it "Period"?

Answer (score 5):

This is probably a matter of personal preference, but I would call this the "**interval**" for this case, and to be agnostic to what the axis of the line graph is representing more generally.

But worth noting that depending on the nature of the data, you can often be more specific:

- the "timestep" or "sample rate" for high resolution time-series data
- the "period" for cyclical data
- the "width" or "distance" (if the context allows)
- etc...

Comment: I have also seen this called "delta" or "periodicity".

Comment: The term _period_ is in my view better reserved for the length of a cycle. For example, monthly data often show some tendency to seasonal cycles; the length of the period would then be 12 months, not 1 month.